# How to layout parent of ASDisplayNode in AsyncDisplayKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asyncdisplaykit

i want to do like on this picture:
[image]

i do  templateDisplayNode:

```
@interface TemplateDisplayNode : ASDisplayNode

    @property (nonatomic, strong) ASDisplayNode *headerNode;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) ASDisplayNode *ContentNode;
    - (void)addContentNode:(ASDisplayNode *)contentNode;

    @end

    @implement TemplateDisplayNode

    - (instancetype)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            [self createSubviews];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)createSubviews {
        [self createHeaderNode];
        [self createContentNode];
    }

    - (void)addContentNode:(ASDisplayNode *)contentNode {
        [self.contentNode addSubnode:contentNode];
    }

    - (void)createHeaderNode {
        self.headerNode = [[ASDisplayNode alloc] init];
        self.headerNode.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self addSubnode:self.headerNode];
    }

    - (void)createContentNode {
        self.contentNode = [[ASDisplayNode alloc] init];
        self.contentNode.style.flexGrow = YES;
        [self addSubnode:self.contentNode];
    }

    - (ASLayoutSpec *)layoutSpecThatFits:(ASSizeRange)constrainedSize {

        CGFloat mainScreenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

        NSMutableArray *mainStackContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        if (self.headerNode) { 

            self.headerNode.style.preferredSize = CGSizeMake(mainScreenWidth, 48);
            [mainStackContent addObject:self.headerNode];
        }
        if (self.contentNode) {
            [mainStackContent addObject:self.contentNode];
        }
        ASStackLayoutSpec *contentSpec =
        [ASStackLayoutSpec
         stackLayoutSpecWithDirection:ASStackLayoutDirectionVertical
         spacing:0
         justifyContent:ASStackLayoutJustifyContentStart
         alignItems:ASStackLayoutAlignItemsStretch
         children:mainStackContent];

        return contentSpec;
    }

    @end
```

and create page of TemplateDisplayNode class:

```
@interface Page1Node : TemplateDisplayNode

@end

@implement Page1Node

- (ASLayoutSpec *)layoutSpecThatFits:(ASSizeRange)constrainedSize {
    [super layoutSpecThatFits:constrainedSize];

}

@end
```

And use it in ASViewController:

```
@interface MyViewController : ASViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCustomASViewControllerWithTableNode *myTableNodeViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Page1Node *page1node;

@end

@implement MyViewController

- (instancetype)init {
    self.page1node = [[Page1Node alloc] init];
    self = [super initWithNode:self.page1node];

    if (self) {
        [self createMyTableNodeViewController];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)createMyTableNodeViewController {
    self.myTableNodeViewController = [[MyCustomASViewControllerWithTableNode alloc] init];
    [self.page1node addContentNode:self.myTableNodeViewController.node]; //add TableNode like content on page1node
    [self addChildViewController:self.myTableNodeViewController];
    [self.myTableNodeViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

@end
```

MyCustomASViewControllerWithTableNode:

```
@interface MyCustomASViewControllerWithTableNode : ASViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) ASTableNode *tableNode;
@end
...
- (instancetype)init {
    _tableNode = [[ASTableNode alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self = [super initWithNode:_tableNode];

    if (self) {
        _tableNode.dataSource = self;
        _tableNode.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}
```

and when i run it, I see a table in the content field, but I can not scroll the table, because Size frame ContentNode = {0; 0}; 
How to make layout correctly in order to set the size? If I do the same thing, but without using TemplateDisplayNode, then everything works. I would like to use TemplateDisplayNode to remove a lot of duplicate code for similar pages.
AsyncDisplayKit documentation is not advised to use:

```
[super layoutSpecThatFits:constrainedSize];
```

If I remove this line, then I do not go into layoutSpecThatFits in TemplateDisplayNode.
Advise how to be? What solutions can be?

Comment: Could you please show the init of your LDPFeedNodeController?

Comment: sorry, FeedNodeController =  MyCustomASViewControllerWithTableNode. i added init of MyCustomASViewControllerWithTableNode.